# Draw several rectangles using mouse in Qt

Tags: android, c++, rectangles, qpainter

I would like to create a Graphical User Interface which allows the user to draw as many rectangles as he wants on an image using the left button of his mouse.
The paint method has already been implemented in a QGraphicsItem subclass:

```
void ImageGraphicsItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const  QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
if(mousePressed){

    painter->drawPixmap(0,0,*pixmap);
    if(selectedTool==1){       
        painter->drawRect(y)
    }

    drawStarted=true;
    painter->setPen(Qt::blue);
}

// The rectangle is not erased after the user unpresses the left button
else if(drawStarted){
    QPainter *tempPainter=new QPainter(pixmap);
    if(selectedTool==1){

        tempPainter->drawRect(y);
        tempPainter->setPen(Qt::blue);

    }
    painter->drawPixmap(0,0,*pixmap);

}

}
```

I have also reimplemented the "mousePress", "MouseMove" and "MouseRelease" methods and the user is able to draw one rectangle.
However, he is not able to draw several rectangles. When he tries, the application says: "QPainter not active" and "two painters can't work with the same QPaintDevice at the same time"

Thank you so much for your help